# Show success block from contact.php within node enviroment

Tags: php, node.js

I know I am overthinking this and I am in need of a little assistance.

I am working on a node website and there is a contact form. To hook this up I pulled out a contact.php file. I have this all hooked up and working, it sends the email perfectly.

The problem comes when I try to provide the user feedback that it was successful. I've tried a couple different things, but nothing wants to display for me. I haven't worked in php in a very long time so please be kind.

I have some basic divs set up in the html

```
div.contactSuccess.alert.alert-success(role='alert') Thank you for sending us an message!
 
div.contactError.alert.alert-danger(role='alert') Sorry something strange happened! Please try again in a little while!
```

The $success variable is the mail function

```
$success = mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
```

and I have tried in the php

```
if($success){
  ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    .contactSuccess {
        display: block;
    }
  <?
}
```

and

```
if($success){
      ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $('.contactSuccess').show();
        </script>
      <?
 }
```

I have also tried

```
if($success){
  echo <div>This works!</div>
}
```

and

```
if($success){
  print <div>This works!</div>
}
```

and also this

```
if($success){
  echo '<script>alert("Please just show something.")</script>';
}
```

Like i said, I have done php in a very long time and I've never done it in a node environment before. A push in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: where are you setting `$success`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It's the mail function. The success is going though and sending the message. I'm just having issues with displaying the message

Comment: presuming your html is a path representation, then `.contactSuccess` is a class not an id, can do it various ways from adding another class to your element which displays it or wrapping in an if statement or showing it with second example `$('.contactSuccess').show();`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes, it is a class. Sorry for my typo. I was trying so many different things. None of the examples above worked. including the the $('.contactSuccess').show(); which is why I am stumped. What other ways can I accomplish this?